# "Too many connections" mysql airflow

Tags: mysql, airflow, airflow-scheduler

When creating tasks, around 7 to 8 thousand of tasks, airflow seems to do something that would cause the "too many connection" issue. I'm wondering if anyone knows what it's implicitly doing? I have tried different configurations of airflow and has the sufficient "max_connections" number in mysql.

Comment: MySQL has a max connections that defaults in the order of 150. To raise it to the several thousand that airflow expects you'll also need to increase the file descriptor limit. I don't know much about airflow but if you can make it create/terminate a connection only when it needs information. Why so many tasks? Are the tasks heavy on database access? Include your MySQL version, OS/distro for MySQL in case the solution is to just give it more connections.

Comment: Can you add more details about airflow, how you create your tasks, where are the MySQL connections created/closed? Just a shot in the dark: If these tasks are generated dynamically, is it possible that you open a connection to MySQL for each of them during their definition? If yes you should not establish a connection before the task is actually executed.

Comment: If you have a MySQL database as a metadata database of Airflow, and you are running the tasks parallelly, airflow will try to connect 7k times to the mysql database